# Android :Scrollview with drag and drop to reorder child component

Tags: java, android

I am Having a trouble to create a ScrollView with drag and drop functionality to reorder it's all components. i don't want to create it using Listview. can anyone help me for this.?Thnaks :)

```
public class ActivityDragAndDrop extends Activity {
    private CustomScrollView customScrollView;
    private LinearLayout llMain;
    private float defaultPos;
    private float heightRequestItem;
    private float halfitemHeight;
    private int lastAddedAt = -1;
    float lastY = -1;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag_and_drop);
        initData();
        initUI();
    }

    private void initData() {
        heightRequestItem = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.item_height);
        halfitemHeight = heightRequestItem / 2;
    }

    private void initUI() {
        customScrollView = (CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMain);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            View vTemp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_tv_tag_name, null);
            if (i != 4 && i != 5) {
                TextView tvTagName = ((TextView) vTemp
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvTagName));
                tvTagName.setText("Tag" + i);
                tvTagName.setTag("" + i);
            }

            vTemp.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
            vTemp.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());

            llMain.addView(vTemp);
        }


    }

    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                defaultPos = view.getY();
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 1);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }

    private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            // handle drag events


            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // no action necessary

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                // no action necessary

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                // no action necessary

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:


                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

                // stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                // view being dragged and dropped
                LinearLayout dropped = (LinearLayout) view;

                // view dragged item is being dropped on
                LinearLayout dropTarget = (LinearLayout) v;

                // update the text in the target view to reflect the data being
                // dropped

                // make it bold to highlight the fact that an item has been
                // dropped


                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // no action necessary

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    private void addBlankviewAt(int pos) {
        Log.v("TT", " pos-->" + pos + " N: " + llMain.getChildCount());

        if (lastAddedAt != -1) {
            llMain.removeViewAt(lastAddedAt);
        }
        View vBlank = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_layout, null);
        llMain.addView(vBlank, pos);

        lastAddedAt = pos;
    }


}
```

R.layout.SingleTv_tagname is a layout which i want to reorder in the scrollview using drag and drop animation. Scroll View is created in initUI() methode.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview  .Yes i have read you dont want to do with listivew.Still check whether it helps for u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This...
magic happens in ACTION_DRAG in which you create copy of orignal layout and then find Yposition of view that you are dragging and then divide this Yposition by the height Of that item.This will give yo position of index in scrollview at which cursor is on screen..then  using addViewAt(view,pos) you can add component. and at last remove orignal view using llMain.removeView(originalView); enjoy :) you r done....

```
public class ActivityDragAndDrop extends Activity
{
    private Rect rect;   
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder;
    private CustomScrollView customScrollView;
    private LinearLayout llMain;
    private float defaultPos;
    private float heightRequestItem ;
    private float halfitemHeight;
    private int  lastAddedAt=-1;
    float lastY=-1;
    float prevPos=-1;
    Display display;
    float screenWidth,screenheight;
    Timer t;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    private int widthRequestItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag_and_drop);
        initData();
        initUI();
    }

    private void initData() 
    {
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        screenheight = display.getHeight();
        heightRequestItem= getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_height);   
        halfitemHeight=heightRequestItem/2;
    }

    private void initUI() 
    {
        customScrollView=(CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        llMain=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llMain);
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            View vTemp=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_tv_tag_name, null);
            TextView tvTagName=((TextView)vTemp.findViewById(R.id.tvTagName));
            tvTagName.setText("Tag"+i);
            tvTagName.setTag(""+i);


            vTemp.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
            vTemp.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());

            llMain.addView(vTemp);
        } 
        View vBlank=inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_layout, null);
        vBlank.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        vBlank.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        llMain.addView(vBlank);
        View vBlank1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_layout, null);
        vBlank1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        vBlank1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        llMain.addView(vBlank1);

        t=new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        findHeight();

                    }
                });
            }
        }, 200);

    }

    private void findHeight() 
    {
        heightRequestItem=llMain.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight();
         widthRequestItem=llMain.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+heightRequestItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener 
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            {
                 rect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(),view.getBottom());

                prevPos=view.getY();
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");

                Point offset = new Point((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY());
                  shadowBuilder = new CustomDragShadowBuilder(view, offset);

                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 1);
                return true;
            }
             else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) 
             {


                 return true;
             } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {


                 return true;
             }
            return false;

        }

    }
    private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener 
    {



        private int FLAG;
        private boolean containsDragable;
        private int _yDelta;

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {




                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

        //view being dragged and dropped
        LinearLayout dropped = (LinearLayout) view;


        //view dragged item is being dropped on
        LinearLayout dropTarget = (LinearLayout) v;





            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                //no action necessary

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //no action necessary

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:       
                //no action necessary

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:




                float lastPos=dropTarget.getY();
                View vBlank=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_tv_tag_name, null);
                ((TextView)vBlank.findViewById(R.id.tvTagName)).setText(((TextView)dropped.findViewById(R.id.tvTagName)).getText());
                vBlank.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
                vBlank.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
                llMain.addView(vBlank, ((int)(lastPos/heightRequestItem)));
                llMain.removeView(dropped);

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //no action necessary

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
            return true;
        }


    }


    public class CustomDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

        private Point _offset;


        public CustomDragShadowBuilder(View view, Point offset) {

            // Stores the View parameter passed to myDragShadowBuilder.
            super(view);


            _offset = offset;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch) {


            size.set(getView().getWidth(), getView().getHeight());


            touch.set(_offset.x, _offset.y);
        }

        }


}
```

//CustomScrollView.java

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView{

    private OnScrollChanged onScrollChanged;
    private boolean hasScrollListener;




    private int mMaxYOverscrollDistance;    

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initBounceScrollView();
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initBounceScrollView();

    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initBounceScrollView();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) 
    {
        //if(AppConstants.DEBUG)Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG,"onScrollChanged: "+l+":"+t+":"+oldl+":"+oldt);

        if(hasScrollListener)
        {
            onScrollChanged.onScrollChanged(this,l, t, oldl, oldt);

        }

        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX,
            boolean clampedY) {

        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
    }

    public OnScrollChanged getOnScrollChanged() {
        return onScrollChanged;
    }

    public void setOnScrollChanged(OnScrollChanged onScrollChanged) {

        this.onScrollChanged = onScrollChanged;
        hasScrollListener = true;
    }

     private void initBounceScrollView()
    {
        //get the density of the screen and do some maths with it on the max overscroll distance
        //variable so that you get similar behaviors no matter what the screen size


        mMaxYOverscrollDistance = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height_pullrefresh);//(int) (density * MAX_Y_OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) 
    { 

        //if(AppConstants.DEBUG) Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "deltaX  "+deltaX+"  "+ deltaY+" "+ scrollX+" "+ scrollY+" "+ scrollRangeX+" "+ scrollRangeY+" "+ maxOverScrollX+" "+ maxOverScrollY+" "+ isTouchEvent);         
        if(scrollY==(-mMaxYOverscrollDistance) && isTouchEvent)
        {
            if(onScrollChanged!=null)   onScrollChanged.onOverScrolledAtMax();
        }
        //This is where the magic happens, we have replaced the incoming maxOverScrollY with our own custom variable mMaxYOverscrollDistance; 
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, mMaxYOverscrollDistance, isTouchEvent);  
    }

}
```

//OnScrollChanged.java interface

```
public interface OnScrollChanged {
     void onScrollChanged(View v,int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt );
     void onOverScrolledAtMax();
     void onOverScrolledStarted();
     void onOverScrolledEnded();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show code for the CustomScrollView too?